# Поиск текста в базе, проблема скорости

Tags: search, php, mysql

Пользователь ввел текст

Вначале нужно проверить есть ли этот текст в базе а потом добавить

Ясный пень, что скорость поиска текста будет очень медленная (относительно)

Текст не более 255 символов, ищется в базе целиком, без всяких там like

Я подумал что наверное лучше сделать 2 столбика, 1 с текстом, второй с md5 текста и искать по md5

как такое решение, грамотное или еще что можете предложить?

и какой индекс сделать у md5, уникальный?

Comment: Все верно. Индекс на поле md5 уникальный.

Можно использовать более короткий хешь, crc32 - там возможные значения умещяется в int, и выборка с индексом летать будет.

Comment: @cromax уникальный ни к чему. просто индекс.

Comment: Возможно crc32 не лучший вариант. Вот [обзор хэшей](http://habrahabr.ru/post/178955/) на Хабре.

Comment: да и md5 ни к чему. просто индекс на текст. это дело индекса — думать, как эффективно искать, велосипед уже изобретён.

Comment: @Vlad это пока вам не понадобился "уникальный" индекс на text

Comment: А если потом понадобится искать по части текста?

И где гарантия, что пользователь знаки препинания введет так же как в тексте? Или заглавными что-то случайно написал?

Может все-таки какую-нить поисковую систему прикрутите? Что-то типа [Sphinx`a](http://sphinxsearch.com/)

Тогда можно будет не только по части искать, но и с грамматическими ошибками/опечатками пользователя при наборе бороться. Объем текста можно будет увеличить и т.д.

Comment: @ВОРОН, я попытался придумать, в каких ситуациях нужен именно жесткий поиск, как хочет ТС. Первое, что пришло в голову: отслеживание посылки по номеру (длинный, до 255 символов, цифро-буквенный номер).

А вообще, сомневаюсь, что сжатие 255 байт в 32 даст ощутимый прирост скорости перебора-проверки.

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев*

Все верно, можно добавить уникальный или обычный индекс на поле md5-хэшем вставляемой строки. Можно использовать более короткий хеш, например, crc32 - его возможно значения умещаются в тип INT.